# Does it violate GRASP if a Character class checks if it can carry a weapon?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, language-agnostic

Before I ask my question, I'm aware of Eric Lippert's [Wizard and Warrior series](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/).

I'm trying to understand [GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)), but I'm having a hard time determining if this class violates GRASP.

Suppose if I had the following `Character` class:

```
class Character(ABC):

        def __init__(self, name, strength, attributes):
            self._name = name
            self._strength = strength
            self._attributes = attributes
            self._inventory = []
            self._found_attributes = []
            self._cannot_equip = False
            self._equipped = True

        def add(self, game_object):
            self._inventory.append(game_object)

        # I may obviously want to do more checks, such as required strength,
        # if I currently have another weapon equipped, etc..
        def try_equip(self, game_object):
            if self._check_for_conflicting_attributes(game_object):
                return self._cannot_equip
            return self._equipped

        def _check_for_conflicting_attributes(self, game_object):
            for attrib in self._attributes:
                if game_object.contains_attribute(attrib):
                    self._found_attributes.append(attrib)
            return len(self._found_attributes) > 0
```

`Weapon` class:

```
class GameWeapon(ABC):

    # imports and other methods left out. 

    def __init__(self, name, required_strength, damage, attributes):
        self._name = name
        self._required_strength = required_strength
        self._damage = damage
        self._attributes : List[Attributes] = attributes

    def contains_attribute(self, attribute):
        return attribute in self._attributes
```

and `Main`:

```
def main():

    wizard_attributes : List[Attributes] = []
    wizard_attributes.append(Attributes.LongBlade)
    wizard_attributes.append(Attributes.Reloadable)

    wiz = Wizard("Gandalf", 100, wizard_attributes)

    sword_attributes : List[Attributes] = []
    sword_attributes.append(Attributes.LongBlade)
    sword = Sword("Standard Sword", 5, 10, sword_attributes)

    # Will print false
    print(wiz.try_equip(sword))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Explanation:**

Both `Wizard` and `Sword` have attributes, for example, `Wizard` might have attribute called `mana-drinker` and `Sword` might have `LongBlade` as an attribute. Before adding a `LongBlade` weapon to my character inventory, I check for specific attributes, for example, a Wizard can't use a Sword, so I check for `LongBlade` and if the weapon has that attribute it will prevent that weapon from being added to the character inventory.

One topic that's always mentioned is class responsibility, if the `Character` class does violate GRASP is it because it has the responsibility of checking and verifying if it could add a weapon to the player inventory?

My larger question is, how do you know when a class may be violating GRASP? What if I want the class or subclass to be responsible for check before adding a weapon or doing another task? Is it still a violation?

Comment: Your GRASP link is dead.  Do you have another?  A normal web page is preferable to a slideshow.

Comment: @JimmyJames - It's to a presentation, it works

Comment: Right, presentations are not a good for this purpose.  People aren't going want to sit through a presentation to understand your question.  Most people won't spend more than a minute or two looking at it.  The wikipedia link in the answer below would be preferable.

Comment: @JimmyJames - I'll change the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to the immediate example**

GRASP includes the pattern [`Information Expert`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Information_expert), which states that whatever object contains the information required to perform an action is responsible for performing it.

In your example, your `Sword` does not contain sufficient information to determine whether a character can equip it or not. This information resides in the `Character` class. Therefore, it should be the `Character`'s responsibility to perform the action.

**To answer the broader question**

Whether your objects violate GRASP differs depending on *which* pattern it violates. A violation of the `Information Expert` pattern mentioned above, for example, can be recognized because you find your method doing more calls for data from another object than it does consulting its own; there is not enough information to perform your task so you do an unreasonable amount of reach to gather that information.

When I apply GRASP to a design, I follow a sort of checklist.

- Do the methods and members all make sense together (have `high cohesion`) or should they be divided into multiple smaller, more specialized components?
- Can cohesion be improved or operations simplified by extracting functionality from one object to another which has a greater amount of the data required for the operation (`Information expert`)
- How tightly knit are objects with other objects? Are they too `tightly coupled` with their dependencies, such that one cannot exist without the other, changing one irrevocably means I have to change the other and are their reuse too limited as a result of either of these cases.
- What is the relationship between an object and any other object it might instantiate. Does instantiation follow the `creator` pattern rules.
- Do I have operations that depend on conditional statements based on some attribute on otherwise interchangeable components? Can I abstract these components in order to avoid branching? (`Polymorphism`)
- Does any of my objects contain members such that I cannot extend the functionality of the contained member without altering functionality on the object containing it? (`Protected variation`)
- Can I reduce coupling between any objects by introducing an intermediary object? (`Indirection`)
- Do my data-model classes contain input handling or otherwise allow data-models to be directly modified without an intermediary `controller`?
- Is there any problem in my domain that can be simplified by the introduction of an intermediary that is not itself part of the domain? (`Pure fabrication`)

As you may notice, almost every bulletin on that checklist relates to *interaction between objects*, and that's because GRASP does not exist in isolation. In general, it does not make sense to ask if an individual object violates GRASP, because with only one object you only have one locus of responsibility. It's when you connect objects to one another that the *overall design* of the system may violate GRASP.

**Edit**

To clarify, the `Information Expert` pattern does not state that an object can never request information from another object, but rather that the object that needs to ask for *the least* amount of information should be responsible for the task.

Given the situation in the question, `Character` contains a rule stating it cannot equip `Weapon`s with the `LongBlade` attribute. Therefore, all we need to do to find out if the `Character` is allowed to equip a weapon, is ask for the `Weapons` attribute contains `LongBlade`.

If we reverse this responsibility, and instead give `Weapon` the responsibility of deciding **without changing anything else**, the game asks the `Character` to equip a `Weapon`, the `Character` asks the `Weapon` if it can be equipped, and the `Weapon` asks *the same `Character`* if it is allowed to be equipped. The decision ultimately then remains in `Character`, and it should have the responsibility to make it.

Comment: Does the `Rule` class suggestion presented by Eric Lippert violate GRASP? The `Rule` class will ask objects for information and decide what to do. Is the `Rule` class an example of a Pure Fabrication as discussed in the presentation?

Comment: *Therefore, it should be the Character's responsibility to perform the action/you find your method doing more calls for data from another object than it does consulting its own* - Bare with me here, but my `Character` class is not asking for information(calling a getter), it's passing the information into `Sword` and let `Sword` give you the result. I've updated my code, does it still violating GRASP. I added the `Weapon` class, didn't change thing else.

Comment: All that being said, how would you re-write it so that it doesn't violate GRASP?

Comment: At the risk of missing something by not having read the entire article series, his explanation of the `Rule` class does intuitively seem to violate both `Information Expert` and `Polymorphism`. If the difference between a `Character` derived class can be described by an allowance in which weapons can be equipped, then this can be encoded in `Character`'s concretion, and can also be enforced by the object itself, since it contains the information on allowed `Weapon` types. Conversely, the `Weapon` could encode which `Character`s are allowed to equip it, which reverses the responsibility.

Comment: How would it check what weapon the `Character` is holding without asking? which is what my sample code is doing when it checks the attributes.

Comment: By calling `contains_attribute` on the `Weapon`, you are not asking the `Weapon` to *make a decision*, this is the key aspect. You are asking for an attribute that `Character` can use to make a decision, since it holds the information on whether `LongBlade` is acceptable or not. If you reverse that responsibility without changing anything else, `Character` asks `Weapon` if it can be equipped, which in turn asks that same `Character` whether its attributes are acceptable, since it doesn't contain that information. The pattern is about which class is *responsible* for a particular decision.

Comment: Additionally, going back a bit, the proposed `Rule` class **could** be a `pure fabrication`, if by *omitting* it, there is an increase in system complexity or coupling, or a reduction in cohesion.

Comment: So, either way, regardless if `Character` asks `Weapon` or `Weapon` asks `Character`, i'm in violation of GRASP, how would I do it so that I'm not in violation? I just don't see how without one object asking the other.

Comment: I apologize, it seems I'm being unclear. What I am trying to say is that no, by having your `Character` ask `Weapon` for its type and then making a decision based on that, you are **not** in violation of GRASP. `Character` is the information expert in regards to what weapon types are valid, and as such given a weapon it can make the decision based on it. Therefore `Character` should have the responsibility - like it does in your example. You have correctly applied the `Information Expert` pattern, since `Character` does not defer its decision to another class.

Comment: So, to be clear `Character` is not in violating of GRASP? I give it the necessary information(`Weapon`), and ask it to make a decision as to weather or not it can be added.

Comment: That's correct. I've added an edit in my answer to clarify how the information expert pattern is to be applied.

Comment: @EmilyScott: correct, to extend the metaphor a bit, perhaps the `Character` is a weapons master and can use almost any weapon or almost anything *as* a weapon, only that particular character would know what could be used.  Eric’s `Rules` wouldn’t cover it, because there wouldn’t be a rule for that (except to go through the characters skills and see, but even that would fail for can use non-weapon x as a weapon, as that wouldn’t be an enumerated skill but a result determined at runtime) and so `Rules` would have to ask the character anyway.